# Custom sorting in for loop

Tags: python, c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

Let's say I am given an array of n points(pair of coordinates). I want to generate a 2D array of points, where i<sup>th</sup> row has all elements sorted according to their distance from the i<sup>th</sup>  point. There may be better and more efficient algorithms to get the final result, but for some reasons I want to do it by *naive* algorithm, i.e., brute-force. Also I don't want to write my own sorting function.

In C language, one can use the `qsort` function, but it's compare function only takes two parameters whereas I will be needing to pass three parameters: the reference point and two other points to be compared.

In Python too, one can use `sorted` function, but again, it's key function only takes one parameter, whereas in this case, I will need to pass two parameters.

So how do I do it?

Comment: What's a "row" in your setup?

Comment: Dirty solution: pass the reference point as a global variable.

Comment: In the 2D array, ith row contains all n points, sorted according to their distance from the point a_i where a_i is the ith point in the input 1D array of n points.

Comment: @chux: yes, that should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a function-making function to create a custom distance function for each point.

```
pts = [(1,1), (3,4), (1,8), (7,6)]

def mk_distsq(a):
    def distsq(b):
        return ((b[0]-a[0])**2 + (b[1]-a[1])**2)**0.5
    return distsq

dist = [sorted(pts, key=mk_distsq(pt)) for pt in pts]
```

Comment: Alternatively, just write a regular distance function (or squared distance, which gives the same sort order) and use `functools.partial` to fix one of the arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
grid = [sorted(l, key=lambda x: distance(x, y)) for y in l]
```

Lambdas can be closures. This can be error-prone, though, since when the value of `y` changes on the next iteration, all the lambdas start using the new value. I believe that doesn't affect this code, but I'd feel safer using `functools.partial`:

```
grid = [sorted(l, key=functools.partial(distance, x)) for x in l]
```

Comment: The value of `y` changing doesn't make the lambda error-prone - in fact, your example with `partial` relies on the same behavior (`x` changes with each iteration, and all the `partial`s start using the new value).

Comment: @lvc: Nope! The old `partial` objects (if they were still around) would still be using their original `x` values. The argument is bound at the time the `partial` object is created.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function that takes the relevant information (reference, two points) and maps it to a distance:

```
def deteremineDistance(reference, pt1, pt2):
    #determine distances according to your definition and store it in variable "dist"
    return dist
```

The result of this function then can be sorted, while keeping track of their correspondence to the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

For the C part of the post:
Use a global variable.  Should be fine, except not multi-threaded safe.

Assume OP has the compare function to compare 2 points distance from a reference point:

```
int compare(const pt *a, const pt2 *b, const pt2 *ref);
```

Add

```
static const pt2 *local_ref;

static int local_compare(pt **a, pt2 **b) {
  return compare(*a, *b, local_ref);
}

void qsort_list(pt2 *list[], size_t n, pt2 *ref) {
  local_ref = ref;
  qsort(list,  n, size(*list), local_compare);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the list of coordinates is bound to `pairs`.  Then here's a 1-statement way:

```
[sorted(pairs,
        key=lambda point: (point[0] - ref[0])**2 + (point[1] - ref[1])**2)
 for ref in pairs]
```

For example, given:

```
pairs = [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

that produces:

```
[[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)],
 [(2, 3), (1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 5)],
 [(3, 4), (2, 3), (4, 5), (1, 2)],
 [(4, 5), (3, 4), (2, 3), (1, 2)]]
```

Note that there's no need to extract square roots, unless you want the actual distances.  For purposes of sorting, you get the same order by looking at the squares of the distances.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a nested for loop with the outside one looking at the ith point.  then inside loop and calculate all the distances.  After calculation use a native python sort for that row and then add it to the main 2d array.